# Linting check isn't passing on GitHub but doesn't trigger locally

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I have a [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/26028/files#diff-65fce10ca1d99a4d6e27bdaa21447eab5c18bccdf04a677abe9fa94bbb4f31a3R5) thats struggling to get past linting.

```
Python's open(...) seems to be used to open text files without explicitly specifying encoding='utf8':

test/functional/feature_chain_arg_collision.py:        with open(
Success: no issues found in 251 source files
^---- failure generated from lint-python-utf8-encoding.py
```

Running the linter locally doesn't trigger the error warning.

The only place I use open is in the functional test

```
with open(
             os.path.join(self.nodes[0].datadir, "bitcoin.conf"), "a", encoding="utf8"
         ) as conf:
             conf.write(f"includeconf={inc_conf_file_path}\n")

         with open(inc_conf_file_path, "w", encoding="utf8") as conf:
             conf.write("chain=regtest\n")
```

I'm running

```
/Users/${USER}/git/bitcoin/test/lint/lint-python-utf8-encoding.py
```

with my file staged in git.

Comment: The version of the linter in CI may differ from the one you use locally, which may cause it to trigger or not trigger in slightly different conditions. I'd suggest commenting on the PR to get guidance from other reviewers. I don't think this is the right place to ask.